# Regex matching on awk in command line

Tags: awk, regular-expression

I'm trying to get the filename from unrar command verbose and deleting them all through command line.

The unrar command output is similar to this:

```
Extracting  BucketSort.cpp                                            OK 
Extracting  BucketSort.vcxproj                                        OK 
Extracting  BucketSort.vcxproj.filters                                OK 
Extracting  BucketSort.lastbuildstate                                 OK 
Extracting  BucketSort.log                                            OK 
Extracting  BucketSort.obj                                            OK 
Extracting  BucketSort.pch                                            OK
```

So I came up with this awk command so far:

```
unrar e BucketSort.rar | awk '{if (match($0,/Extracting\s*([\w|.]+)\s*OK/,m)) print m[0]}'
```

but nothing is printed. When I leave just the word "Extracting" to match I can see "Extracting" for all the extracting files. So it's not recognizing  something written in regex but I don't know what it is. Do you know what's wrong with the expression?

PS: You can check the regex expression [here](https://regex101.com/r/pW2vR4/1).

Comment: It looks like you're used to Perl, actually.  In `awk` you need to backslash-escape a lot more of the "special" bits of regexes, including parentheses, and (I believe) `+` as well.

Comment: I think GNU awk (which seems to be what's implied here, given the array argument to `match`) supports the perl-like `\s` and `\w` classes, however it's not clear to me how `[\w|.]` should be interpreted. Regardless, it seems to be a heavy-handed way to split what appear to be simple whitespace delimited fields - why not just do `$1=="Extracting" && $3=="OK"`

Comment: gawk doesn't seem to like `\w` inside brackets (although I can't find documentation to support this claim). Both of these provide the output you seek: `(\S+)` and `([[:alnum:]_.]+)`. references https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/GNU-Regexp-Operators.html and https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Bracket-Expressions.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
unrar e BucketSort.rar | awk '/^Extracting/ {print $2}'
```

Comment: Thank you DopeGhoti. Your expression does work but do you know why the expression I wrote doesn't? I'm wondering just in case I need to check another kind of output that I need.

Comment: I think it's because your regex checker settings on the site you linked were for perl-compatible regex, and awk uses a slightly different flavor in which, as a comment on your OP mentions, needs a lot more escaping of special characters.  `awk` is more Cish than perlish.